# Public holidays list for European countries from 2010-2020 using R?

Tags: r, date, web-scraping

Currently, manually noting down the public holidays by googling year by year.
But can we somehow automate this ?
e.g.

France public holidays in 2010,2011,2012,-......2020
or 
Italy

Crude way:
[image]

Comment: We can use `utils::download.file` to download an URLs html. From there we can use `xml2::read_html` and/or `rvest::html_nodes` to extract information.

Comment: Maybe try to scrape this website? for example for France 2019: https://www.officeholidays.com/countries/france/2019

Comment: Another useful package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/

Comment: @zx8754, Thanks for suggestion. That website has from 2015.

Comment: @dario, Thanks for sharing an appoach. So, this will land me to extarct 2010-2020 1 by 1 depending on  declared countries ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'So, this will land me to extarct 2010-2020 1 by 1 depending on declared countries' But it will allow exactly what I stated: You give it an URL, it downloads the html and then you can try to extract the information. *What* information you get depends totally and only on the URL/webpage.

Comment: @dario, So, I should give 20 different URLs to extract 20 different years !. IN this case, I should first find those URLs then. Isn't it ? May be the screenshot I had shared would be an example URL ?

Comment: Exactly. The screenshot you shared is what reminded me of this approach !

Comment: @dario. Oh ok. Thanks for solution. How can I accept it ?

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a solution, so don't worry about accepting. But thanks for the appreciation ;)

Comment: I've had good experiences with https://holidayapi.com